# Sping Data Source configuración provoca cortes puntuales con servidor

Tags: java, spring, base-de-datos

Con el siguiente `DataSource` configurado:

```
public DataSource dataSourceSpring() throws Exception {

    // DBCP Datasource, enables connection pooling
    final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    LOG.info("EntityDaoConfiguration:: Loading Datasource of type {}", dataSource.getClass().getName());
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("ora.driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("ora.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("ora.user"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("ora.password"));

    // Connection pool configuration.
    dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
    dataSource.setMaxTotal(20);
    dataSource.setMinIdle(5);
    dataSource.setMaxWaitMillis(90000);
    dataSource.setDefaultQueryTimeout(null);
    dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");

    LOG.debug("SCHEMA:" + dataSource.getUrl() + "-" + dataSource.getUsername());
    return dataSource;
}
```

Se producen excepciones puntuales del tipo:

> detailedMessage "Error calling server\nI/O error on GET request for
>   "URL classes=class":Connection has been shut down; nested exception is
>   java.io.InterruptedIOException: Connection has been shut
>   down\nConnection has been shut down" (id=301)  detailMessage
>   "org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   GET request for "URL classes=class":Connection has been shut down;
>   nested exception is java.io.InterruptedIOException: Connection has
>   been shut down" (id=302)

Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Revisaría los mensajes en el servidor/bd. Si la conexiòn fuè cerrada por error/excepciòn puede aparecer ahí

Comment: ¿Se te desconecta cuando te conectas desde SQL Developer o desde otros sitios? Parece un problema de red.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero no aparece nada en absoluto ni en tomcat ni en el alert de oracle :(

Comment: revisa tu GET por que te esta diciendo que no encuentra URL puede ser que no tengas bien tu dispatstcher-servlet.

Comment: No parece que sea ese el problema tampoco, ya que ocurre cada vez en un sitio distinto y otras veces no ocurre, ejecutando exactamente lo mismo.